# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme error without changing code

Tags: android, styles, runtimeexception

I have a weird problem where I didn't change the code of the MainActivity, and still get the run time exception:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity.

My onCreate of MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    instance = this;
    instance.setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    initializeSystem();
    initializeUI();

    test();
}
```

Styles that I use:

```
<style name="AppTheme" speParent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/dialog_progress_foreground</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/menuStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Splashscreen" speParent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen_drawable</item>

</style>
```

Now, the weird part. I'm using a versioning system so I tried the commit before this one. It works and doesn't crash.
That commit has some dialogs showing in the test function of MainActivity. They were commented out in the last commit.
When I return it to code (show dialogs) the code still crashes.

Of course I changed some other classes, but they are not used in the MainActivity without manual activation, so that shouldn't be it.

I'm really at loss. I guess I could rollback my commit, but I strongly dislike not understanding whats going on.

And since I'm using proper styles it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you made a typo for the parent property on style tag

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
...
</style>
```

and

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.Splashscreen" parent="AppTheme">
...
</style>
```

Comment: haha yes, I just found it couple of minutes ago. Refactoring and blindly clicking "ok" is the culprit.